# Solving system of linear eqaution in special cases

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, numerical-methods, computer-science

I have to solve for $Ax=B$. Here the diagonal elements of $A$ are $-1$ and all other elements are $1$. $A$ is $n \times n$ matrix . In this special case can we solve for $x$ quickly?

EDIT: quick is in terms of asymptotic complexity.

Comment: $A$ is not invertible (at least) for $n=2$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "quickly"? Do you mean how fast computers can solve the system or whether there is a closed form for the solution for any $n$?

Comment: It is invertible for $n \neq 2$, since $A= e e^T -2I$, and $e e^T$ has eigenvalues $n,0$.

Comment: @njguliyev The system need not be solvable are all values of A and B. If it not solvable we can deal with it separately.

Comment: Others pointed out that $A=ee^T-2I$, I just wanted to mention that this kind of matrix looks like [Householder transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) which is well known and even was named among 10 top algorithms of 20th century.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $A= e e^T -2I$, where $e=(1,1,...,1)^T$.

It is easy to check that $\sigma(A) = \{n-2,-2\}$, hence for $n \neq 2$, $A$ is invertible.

I will assume $n \neq 2$ subsequently.

Suppose $b = \alpha e + v$, where $v \bot e$. Then if we let $x = \frac{\alpha}{n-2} e - \frac{1}{2} v$, it is easy to check that $Ax = b$.

It is trivial to compute $\alpha = \frac{1}{n} \langle b , e \rangle$, and $v = b-\alpha e$ to get
$$ x = \frac{\langle b , e \rangle}{n(n-2)} e - \frac{1}{2} (b - \frac{1}{n} \langle b , e \rangle e) = \frac{\langle b , e \rangle}{2(n-2)} e - \frac{1}{2} b$$
I count $3n+2$ flops.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $n > 2$.  Let $e = [1 \cdots 1]^T \in \mathbb R^n$.  Then $A = e e^T - 2I$ and I noticed from Matlab experiments that
\begin{equation}
A^{-1} = \frac{e e^T - (n-2)I}{2(n-2)}.
\end{equation}
You can check this by multiplying it out.

It follows that 
\begin{equation}
A^{-1} b = \frac{(e^T b) e - (n-2) b}{2(n-2)}.
\end{equation}

So solving $Ax = b$ in this case requires $O(n)$ flops.